# Evaluate $\int_0^1y ( ( 1+\frac{1}{y^2} )\log (1+y^2) -1 )dy=-1+\frac{\pi^2}{24}+\log 2$ and a related generalization

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, power-series

Let $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$ thus $\xi=xy^2<1$ and we can use the series expansion $$\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+\xi}{1-\xi}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\xi^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
to get $$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^1 y\log\frac{1+xy^2}{1-xy^2}dxdy=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)(n+1)^2},$$
where my computations are justified by **Fubini-Tonelli** and since the series is **uniformly convergent**.

On the other hand using in the integrand $\log\frac{A}{B}=\log A-\log B$ one can consider 
$$\int_0^1 y\log (1+xy^2)dx=y\int_0^1 \log (1+xy^2)dx,$$ as the corresponding first summand (of the integral with respect to $x$) and **integration by parts**, $u=\log (1+xy^2)$ and $dv=dx$, yields $$y \left(  \left( 1+\frac{1}{y^2} \right)\log (1+y^2) -1 \right) ,$$
as previous definite integral, if we take now $\int_0^1\ldots dy$, how I prove the result that provide* to me **Wolfram Alpha**?

> **Question 1.**  Can you compute, or reference in this site, the integral that we need to get the summand $\pi^2$ in 
>   $$\int_0^1y (  ( 1+\frac{1}{y^2} )\log (1+y^2) -1 )dy=-1+\frac{\pi^2}{24}+\log 2?$$
>   I am assuming that the summand $\log 2$ is easily to obtain. And the second summand to get the whole series should be the same computations.

As remarks I say that this online resource knows how compute the series as $\log 16-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, and all integrals (that I need to show previous identity) except a closed form for the double integral* when I've used the standard time of computation that provide us.

> **Question 2.** Can you compute some generalization (then if this wasn't in the literature, now will be in this site for all users) like as 
>   $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 x^\alpha y^\beta\log\frac{1+x^\gamma y^\delta}{1-x^\gamma y^\delta}dxdy,$$
>   for integers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$? **Thanks in advance.**

I hope some answer for this second question, and accept one good generalization, as soon as possible/reasonable.

Comment: **The code in Wolfram Language were respectively**

integrate _0^1 integrate _0^1 y log ((1+xy^2)/(1-xy^2)) dx dy
integrate _0^1 y log ((1+xy^2)) dx
integrate _0^1 y (-1 + (1 + y^(-2)) Log[1 + y^2]) dy
integrate _0^1 y log ((1-xy^2)) dx
integrate _0^1 ((-1 + x y^2) (-1 + Log[1 - x y^2]))/y dy
integrate _0^1 y -(-y^(-1) + y) Log[1 - y^2])dy

Comment: I don't know if there is connection with some of the computations from Janous article, provide us [emis.de](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/020_06_JIPAM/020_06_www.pdf)

Comment: The last integral has two useless parameters: $\gamma$ and $\delta$ can be removed through the obvious substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an addendum to Marco's answer (the answer for question **2**):

$$ J(\alpha,\beta)=\iint_{(0,1)^2} x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}\text{arctanh}(xy)\,dx\,dy = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2+\alpha)(2n+2+\beta)}$$
can be computed through partial fraction decomposition and:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b}. $$
Namely,

> $$ J(\alpha,\beta) = \color{red}{\frac{\gamma}{2\alpha\beta}+\frac{\alpha\,\psi\left(\frac{\beta+2}{2}\right)-\beta\,\psi\left(\frac{\alpha+2}{2}\right)}{2\alpha\beta(\alpha-\beta)}}$$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and $\psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: **Very thanks much, if you can please add what is** $\psi$. I believe that today I should be choice the best contribution, your answer seem a good candidate to accept as answer by his remarkable quality.

Comment: @user243301: added.

Answer (score 2):

The integral of the question $1$ is not difficult to evaluate. We have $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)\log\left(1+y^{2}\right)-y\right)dy=\int_{0}^{1}y\log\left(1+y^{2}\right)dy+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\left(1+y^{2}\right)}{y}dy-\int_{0}^{1}ydy.
 $$ For the first integral take $y^{2}+1=u
 $ to get $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{2}\log\left(u\right)du=\log\left(2\right)-\frac{1}{2}.
 $$ for the second integral we put $y^{2}=u
 $ and we get $$-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\left(1+u\right)}{u}dy=-\frac{1}{2}\left[\textrm{Li}_{2}\left(-u\right)\right]_{0}^{1}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{24}
 $$ where $\textrm{Li}_{2}\left(x\right)
 $ is the [Dilogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html). The last integral is trivial.

Comment: (+1) You may sleep 10 seconds more tomorrow morning :D

Comment: Very thanks much, now I see how evaluate the integral, the second, those involving the dilogarithm I didn't know how compute, I asked to me, where it came from the summand involving $\pi^2$? Now I yes I see that the computations can be justified. Very thanks much.

Comment: Very thanks much one more time.

Answer (score 1):

**Question One.**
Let
\begin{align}
J=\int_0^1y \left(  \left( 1+\frac{1}{y^2} \right)\log (1+y^2) -1 \right)dy&= \int_0^1   \frac{1}{y}\left( y^2+1 \right)\log (1+y^2)dy - \frac{1}{2}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,( *)
\end{align}
Setting 
\begin{align}
I= \int_0^1   \frac{1}{y}\left( y^2+1 \right)\log (1+y^2)dy 
\end{align}
Substitute $w=1+y^2$ then $y=\sqrt{w-1}$ and $dy=\frac{dw}{2\sqrt{w-1}}$, as $y=0 \to u=1$, and as $y=1 \to u=2$.

\begin{align}
I= \int_1^2   \frac{1}{\sqrt{w-1}}w\log (w)\frac{dw}{2\sqrt{w-1}} =\frac{1}{2}\int_1^2   \frac{w\log (w)}{w-1}dw 
\end{align}

Integrating by parts by letting 
$u=\log (w)$ and $dv=\frac{w}{w-1}=1+\frac{1}{w-1}$, we get $du=\frac{1}{w}$ and $v=w+\ln(w-1)$. So that 
\begin{align}
\int udv=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^2   \frac{w\log (w)}{w-1}dw &=\frac{1}{2}uv-\frac{1}{2}\int vdu
\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\log (w) \left(w+\ln(w-1)\right)\left.\right|_1^2-\frac{1}{2} \int_1^2  {\left(1+\frac{1}
{w}\ln(w-1)\right)dw}
\\
&= \log 2-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\int_1^2  {\frac{\ln(w-1)}{w}dw}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(**)
\end{align}
Again substitute $\theta=-\ln(w-1)$ i.e., $w-1=e^{-\theta}$,   $dw=-e^{-\theta}d{\theta}$, as $w=1\to \theta= \infty$ and $w=2\to \theta =0$

Therefore, 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \int_1^2  {\frac{\ln(w-1)}
{w}dw}&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\theta e^{-\theta}}{1+e^{-\theta}}d\theta}
\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\theta e^{-\theta}}{1- (-e^{-\theta})}d\theta} 
\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}{\theta e^{-\theta}\cdot
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( { - 1} \right)^n e^{ - n\theta } } 
d\theta} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,({\rm{geometric \,\,series}})
\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty \left( { - 1} \right)^n\int_0^{\infty}{\theta \cdot
 { e^{ - (n+1)\theta } } 
d\theta}
\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\Gamma (2)\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\left( { - 1} \right)^n}{(n+1)^2}
\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\left( { - 1} \right)^n}{(n+1)^2}
\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{24}.
\end{align}
Finaly substitue in (**) and then in (*) we get the desired result
\begin{align}
J=\int_0^1y \left(  \left( 1+\frac{1}{y^2} \right)\log (1+y^2) -1 \right)dy =-1+\log 2+\frac{\pi^2}{24}
\end{align}

Comment: Very thanks much, your answer is perfect because I can learn a lot with your details. It is aprecciate and a present for me, now I study your nice computation to get the integral for wich I've asked in this site. Also impresses to me your computations.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Thanks to you, this site would be not possible without people as you.